# Zope ZEO and MailHost

Tags: email, smtp, zope

I have a webpage running with a ZEO server and 2 Zope Servers, one of which is on a different machine from the ZEO server. Both machines have sendmail installed (I can send mails from the shell).

Now in the Zope MailHost object the SMTP Host is set to localhost. Sending mail is only working when the website is accessed on the same server as the ZEO server, otherwise there is an error:

```
SMTPRecipientsRefused'{'my@email.com':'554, 5.7.1 'my@email.com': Relay access denied')}
```

Is there a way to use localhost as SMTP for a MailHost object in Zope with ZEO? I would have guessed that the Zope MailHost uses sendmail from the same server as the Zope instance, but my guess was obviously wrong.

My workaround is currently to use the MailHost object with an external SMTP server.

Comment: This is not a Zope or MailHost issue; it *is* the same server as the zope instance, but that server is not allowed to relay.

Comment: Hmm, I do not understand: I can send an email to the email-address in question from the shell without an error using the 'mail' command. Is it not using the same service as Zope's MailHost?

Comment: `MailHost` opens a connection to `localhost` port 25, the `mail` command probably puts the mail straight in to the outgoing queue.

Comment: I still do not understand. When it is put in the outgoing queue, at a given time there will be a connection to localhost port 25, isn't it? Where is the difference?

Comment: For some reasons, Zope tried to use the IPv6 interface, disabling it fixed this issue.